# How to use svcutil.exe to create client proxy ib WCF?

Tags: wcf

I have written a wcf service which is working fine.
On the client side i am using AddServiceReference feature of VS2008 to generate client proxy, it's also working fine.
Now, for learning purpose i want to generate my client proxy with svcutil.exe tool but i am not able to use it, i have tried but don't know what is missing maybe i am missing some parameters, i know that AddServiceReference feature also uses svcutil.exe to generate proxy at client side.

Anyone please tell me how to use.

Actually my wcf service project is located at C:\Projects\WCFService and my client is at
C:\Projects\WCFClient.

Below is my service class...

```
Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/MathServices/");

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MathOperations), address))
            {
                BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMathOperations), binding, "");              

                ServiceMetadataBehavior metaDataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                metaDataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metaDataBehavior);
                             host.Open();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found that it is better to use WCF without the autogenerated proxies.

Have a look at this video:

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=103

Note: This only works if you have control of both the server and the client side.

Comment: +1  I would also suggest looking at this video:  http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122

Answer (score 0):

Use `svcutil YourServiceUrl` to generate the proxy class.

If your datacontract contains lists, use  `/ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1` or else the proxy class will have arrays instead of lists.